# launch variable activity in PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I have a Android GCM client and a 3rd party server. On the 3rd party server side I'd now like to tell the Android application, which activity to start in the Pending Intent. Is there a possibility to do so?

I cannot hardcode something like

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

because I don't know yet, which Activity I want to launch...
I tried to add a URI on the server side

```
Message msg = new Message.Builder()
            .collapseKey("push")
            .delayWhileIdle(true)
            .addData("ACTION", 
                    "de.company.myApp.Activity.class")
            .addData("MESSAGE",
                    "messageText")
            .build();
```

and to get it on the client side with

```
String intentUri = intent.getStringExtra("ACTION");
```

and

```
Intent notificationIntent = Intent.parseUri(intentUri, 0);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: r u getting de.company.myApp.Activity.class in intentUri string?

Comment: If I have correctly understood your question, I guess, you have "limited" number of activities in your project, it should be limited. And you obviously should know when to start which activity based on what GCM sends. So why not just parse the GCM message, do a bunch of if-else to start an activity? I'm sorry if I got your question wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the "de.company.myApp.Activity.class" to "de.company.myApp.Activity" i.e. remove the .class extension from the class name.
Then while calling Intent do this..

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(intentUri));
```

hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to answer myself with the exact same answer. This is what I was looking for!